# Differential equation with partial fraction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-fractions

How do you separate this differential equation into a partial fraction?

> Solve the following differential equation:
> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2y^2-xy+x^2}{xy-x^2}$$

Comment: **Hint:** I would try substituting $y = v x$, so $y' = v + x v'$ and then proceed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\frac{y}{x}=v$

$$\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = v + x\frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}x} =\frac{2v^2-v+1}{v-1} \\
x\frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}x} = \frac{v^2+1}{v-1} \\
\frac{v-1}{v^2+1}dv = \frac {{\rm d}x}{x} \\
\text{Integrating  both  sides} \\
\int \frac{v-1}{v^2+1}dv =\int \frac {{\rm d}x}{x} \\
\int \frac{v}{v^2+1}dv - \int \frac{1}{v^2+1}dv= \frac {{\rm d}x}{x} \\
\frac{1}{2} \ln(v^2+1) - \tan^{-1}v = lnx + C\\
\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{y^2+x^2}{x^4}\right) = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right) + C $$

Where $C$ is the constant of integration.